# Redirect to External URl in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using the following configuration for controller to redirect to external url.

My application base url is http://www.testcebs.com:8080/SpringSecDemo11/

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tryIt", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String goToGoogle() {
    String redirectUrl = "www.google.com";
     return "redirect:" + redirectUrl;
}
```

On calling the "/tryIt" url it show 404. and Url goes to

http://www.testcebs.com:8080/SpringSecDemo11/www.google.com

Please suggest any way to get out of it.

Regards,
Pranav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix your url string with the protocol, i.e. `http://www.google.com`.

```
final String redirectUrl = "redirect:http://www.google.com";
return redirectUrl;
```